Hydrostatic Pressure Lifting LVP
LVP is about 9 months old, over a vapor barrier, on slab at grade I suspect hydrostatic pressure is the cause.

Can anything be done to salvage these floors? Will placing a dehumidifier make a difference? (I can't get a french drain in quickly. Rains are expected to continue for another 5 days.)

What kind of flooring would be best to replace it with, when the time comes? (It's a modest garage conversion in Florida.)





if you have hydrostatic pressure there should be water on top of the floor

It is unlikely that you have hydrostatic pressure, or water under the flooring.
What is depicted in the picture is usually found from installation error. The ends were hammered excessively causing minor delamination. The damage manifests itself as the seams of the 2 boards do not lay flat. This gets worse over time.
Unfortunately there is no cure. Only replacement.

The floors were installed 9 months ago and were perfectly flat and smooth to the touch, until last week, when the rains came. If it had been an installation issue, why would they have appeared fine until the heavy rains came? (They are all coming up, as seen in the photo. It isn't just in high traffic areas.)
While AI certainly isn't an expert, it says "Concrete subfloors naturally emit moisture, which can be a big problem for LVP flooring."

There should be vapor barrier under the concrete floors that prevent moisture from coming up through the slab.  To prove to others, I put a piece of LVP flooring in a 5 gallon bucket of water and left it for a week. Nothing happened to it.  True LVP has no reaction to moisture.  Ask AI how many sq/ft of LVP flooring it has laid.

Interesting. I understand that moisture barrier would prevent water from rising through it, to touch the LVP. However, it doesn't seem like it would prevent it from getting between the barrier and LVP, from the sides, where it could rise from hydrostatic pressure.
If it's an installation issue, wouldn't there have been some sign of distress, upon installation?

this is the product in question. It's marketed as waterproof: https://www.flooranddecor.com/duralux-performance-flooring/rabun-hickory-rigid-core-luxury-vinyl-plank---foam-back-100997220.html?utm_content=M-Shopping&utm_term=&gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAjw6JS3BhBAEiwAO9waFwiPk7bGpJKvPsyds9m94zr_5s_db-FsKA4aS_WII0CauWdhdqqudhoC6VIQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds

That product has a stone core. there is no wood to swell look at the diagram here: https://www.flooranddecor.com/duralux-performance-flooring/rabun-hickory-rigid-core-luxury-vinyl-plank---foam-back-100997220.html?utm_content=M-Shopping&utm_term=&gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAjw6JS3BhBAEiwAO9waFwiPk7bGpJKvPsyds9m94zr_5s_db-FsKA4aS_WII0CauWdhdqqudhoC6VIQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds  The edges , if tapped too hard will create fissures in the stone core and the core will crumble and not support the edge. the result is the ends coming up. I have seen this other times with very similar products.

The fact that the ends are most all the same, indicates a mechanical default in installation. Something caused by nature would not be so uniform.   If hydrostatic, why didn't the seams come apart on the long sides?

Thank you. That was very helpful. Can you tell me how, in the future, I can determine if it is installed correctly, before I pay the installer? It looked and felt flush. There was the appropriate amount of expansion space between it and walls.

Ture hardcore LVP does not need much room to expand. It is very stable in all directions and at a wide temperature range.  simple check to see if the install is good, is to use a fingernail on the seams. They should be almost imperceptible.
